# Are discrete dynamical systems the same as recurrence relations?

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I've been researching the chaotic nature of some discrete dynamical systems such as $x_{n+1}=\mu x_n (1-x_n)$. This has made me wonder whether all discrete dynamical systems are just recurrence relations (such as the Fibonacci Numbers), and that only some start behaving chaotically. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sense of recurrences, yes the two are the same. Discrete dynamical systems tend to be specified by a (system) of recurrences. However, to see actual mathematically-rigorous chaos, the systems need to satisfy certain criteria. More generally, mathematicians think of discrete dynamical systems as iterative maps, which stretch and fold space onto itself. The nature of this morphing can be used to define and study interesting behavior such as chaos, ergodicity, etc.

You'll find a wonderful reference from this chapter of Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos book:

http://csc.ucdavis.edu/~chaos/courses/ncaso/Readings/ch2.pdf

A classic example is $x_{n+1}=a-x_n^2$, $x_0=0$, for which you get three kinds of behavior, depending on $a$ (picture from the above book):
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you just clarify as to what you mean by "mathematically-rigorous chaos"?

Comment: @Plato: See 2.63 and 2.64 of the above link.